# Using Task.Factory.StartNew for tasks queue

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I want to use a task queue for background stuff in my C# application.

From reading stuff on the web, I understood that calling `Task.Factory.StartNew` will queue a task on the `TaskScheduler` queue.

When I do this, I get a compiler warning because I'm not awaiting the result of `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

But in my case, the calling code is not interested in the result of the task. I have code that deals with a failure in the task but it is not the calling code's responsibility.

I'm trying to understand is my approach correct or is there a more appropriate 'C# way' of doing a task queue.

Comment: Could you post some example code? I'm intrigued about the compiler warning you are getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to use a task queue for background stuff in my C# application.

While this is *possible*, it's almost never the best approach.

Instead of a queue of tasks, what you probably want is either to *throttle* the background tasks (permitting any order), or a queue of *operations* to execute.

If you want to throttle, then check out `SemaphoreSlim`.

If you want a queue of operations, then check out `ActionBlock<T>` from [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Both of these approaches will work with both synchronous and asynchronous operations, and they're both far, far easier than writing your own "task queue".

Comment: Very good point, especially if there are going to be lots of these background tasks

Comment: Reading about `ActionBlock` took my understanding of concurrency in the CLR a giant leap forward, so thanks. (I'm from a Java background). But I think I also understood that `async-await` is just that - a task queue. The feeling is so different so it took me time to realize it's doing just what I need. I'll stick to that as it makes my code very simple. But I'm accepting your answer so it can enlighten other people.